# Implicit Equation: Solve for boundary of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $G(J)$ denote the CDF of $J$. I have an equation of the form

$$ G(V-k) A = k + \int_a^{V-k} J dG(J)$$

for some constants $A$, $k$, $a$. Is there a way I could get an explicit solution for $V$ out of this, without assuming a functional form for $G$?